# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '91229-101' for key 'player_id_2'

Tags: php, sql

Im running account page to a game from this project https://my-aac.org/

I just have a little error when i create a CHARACTER.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '91230-101' for key 'player_id_2'
```

```
Backtrace:

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\system\libs\pot\OTS_Base_DB.php(86): PDO->query('INSERT INTO `pl...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\system\libs\pot\OTS_DB_PDOQuery.php(13): OTS_Base_DB->doQuery('INSERT INTO `pl...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\system\libs\CreateCharacter.php(258): OTS_Base_DB->query('INSERT INTO `pl...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\system\pages\account\create_character.php(25): CreateCharacter->doCreate('Testwebpage', 1, 0, 32, Object(OTS_Account), Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\system\pages\accountmanagement.php(145): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(347): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#6 {main}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REDF8.png)

**OTS_Base_DB.php(86):**

```
$ret = parent::query(...$args);
```

```
private function doQuery(...$args)
    {
        $this->queries++;

        if($this->logged) {
            $startTime = microtime(true);
        }

        $ret = parent::query(...$args);
        if($this->logged) {
            $totalTime = microtime(true) - $startTime;
            $this->log .= round($totalTime, 4) . ' ms - ' . $args[0] . PHP_EOL;
        }

        return $ret;
    }
```

**OTS_DB_PDOQuery.php(13):**

```
return $this->doQuery(...func_get_args());
```

```
<?php

if (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 80000) {
    require LIBS . 'pot/OTS_DB_PDOQuery_PHP71.php';
} else {
    trait OTS_DB_PDOQuery
    {
        /**
         * @return PDOStatement
         */
        public function query()
        {
            return $this->doQuery(...func_get_args());
        }
    }
}
```

**CreateCharacter.php(258):**

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO `player_items` (`player_id` ,`pid` ,`sid` ,`itemtype`, `count`, `attributes`) VALUES ('".$player->getId()."', '".$save_item['pid']."', '".$save_item['sid']."', '".$save_item['itemtype']."', '".$save_item['count']."', $blob);");
```

```
$loaded_items_to_copy = $db->query("SELECT * FROM player_items WHERE player_id = ".$char_to_copy->getId()."");
        foreach($loaded_items_to_copy as $save_item) {
            $blob = $db->quote($save_item['attributes']);
            $db->query("INSERT INTO `player_items` (`player_id` ,`pid` ,`sid` ,`itemtype`, `count`, `attributes`) VALUES ('".$player->getId()."', '".$save_item['pid']."', '".$save_item['sid']."', '".$save_item['itemtype']."', '".$save_item['count']."', $blob);");
        }
```

**create_character.php(25):**

```
$character_created = $createCharacter->doCreate($character_name, $character_sex, $character_vocation, $character_town, $account_logged, $errors);
```

```
if($save) {
    require_once LIBS . 'CreateCharacter.php';
    $createCharacter = new CreateCharacter();

    $character_created = $createCharacter->doCreate($character_name, $character_sex, $character_vocation, $character_town, $account_logged, $errors);
}
```

**accountmanagement.php(145):**

```
require PAGES . 'account/' . $action . '.php';
```

```
else if(file_exists(PAGES . 'account/' . $action . '.php')) {
            require PAGES . 'account/' . $action . '.php';
        }
```

**index.php(347):**

```
require $file;
```

```
if($hooks->trigger(HOOK_BEFORE_PAGE)) {
        if(!$ignore)
            require $file;
    }
```

[image]

I get the same error when create a new character, '91231-101', '91232-101', '91233-101' etc.
My DB is not a empty one.

We get the error and when you check the DB there is the new character with a new ID. It is working, but i get the error at the final of creation of character.

Is it posible to disable this "warning" error log ?

Comment: It sounds like maybe something is trying to insert the same data twice. But we cannot tell what that is, or why, because you provided no code etc. If you need help, please provide a [mre] of the issue including relevant code and data, and the results of your debugging so far. Trying to simply suppress the warning is the wrong approach - it's trying to tell you about a problem that you need to solve, so ignoring it is a bad idea.

Comment: P.S. Why though are you not letting the database create the character ID? If you use an auto-increment ID field then you'd never have a problem with potential duplicate IDs.

Comment: Hello Sir, i have updated/edited the post, hope it helps with more info!
Thx you!

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that `foreach($loaded_items_to_copy as $save_item)` loops more than once, but uses the same ID each time? Have you done any debugging of that, or anything else?

Comment: I just run the web at xampp and solved other minor issues, I dont have done any other test, cuz i dont know how to do that, but now i get this one, it creates the character, the character created is playable in-game without problems. Is it possible to disable this erros logs? This error only appears when we do the last click at CREATE CHARACTER, the page loads and give us this error.

Comment: I tried to disable error logs at `PHP.ini` display_errors=Off and error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT i set ";" to disable it, but it dont work. . .

Comment: I refer you back to my first comment, about not trying to suppress errors

Comment: `This error only appears when we do the last click at CREATE CHARACTER`...well that's possibly a clue. When you say the "last" click, what exactly do you mean? Is there always a fixed number of characters you need to create, or something?

Comment: `When you say the "last" click, what exactly do you mean?`
 Nevermind :D

`Is there always a fixed number of characters you need to create, or something? `

Yes, but is configurable

Comment: 'characters_per_account' => 10, // max. number of characters per account

Comment: Ok. So we still need to work out if something is running the query twice with the same data. Have you debugged `foreach($loaded_items_to_copy as $save_item) {` yet?

Comment: `Have you debugged foreach($loaded_items_to_copy as $save_item) { yet?` How to do that ? :o

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/amp/